# Convert a a dictionary into an array in one line

Tags: python

I'm trying to simplify this:

```
urls = []
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
items = soup.select('.mydiv a')
for item in items:
    url = item['href']
    urls.append(url)
```

... into a single line. Why does the following not work?

```
urls = [].append(item['href'] for item in soup.select('.mydiv a'))
```

I know it's "less readable", but I want to know for educational purposes.

Comment: Is that supposed to be a list comprehension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does the following not work?

```
urls = [].append(item['href'] for item in soup.select('.mydiv a'))
```

Your code appends a single object to your list, namely, a generator object.

The expression inside the parentheses in `append()` is a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) which yields a generator object. Usually generator expressions need to be enclosed in their own set of parentheses but in the case of one argument in the expression (as in your example), their own set of parentheses is not needed.

The syntax of a [comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries) is virtually identical to the syntax for a generator expression, except that generator expressions tend to be enclosed within a pair of parentheses whereas comprehensions are not.

Even though syntactically comprehensions and generator expressions can be identical, whether Python interprets the identical syntax as a comprehension or a generator expression depends on the context.

For example

```
i for i in range(0, 10)
```

refers to a comprehension when enclosed by square brackets `[` `]` or `{` `}` (i.e. in list and set displays -- see previous reference):

```
# Example 1
>>> a = [i for i in range(0, 10)] 
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

However, when it appears, say, as the argument to the `append()` method of `list`s, the above is interpreted as a generator expression:

```
# Example 2
>>> b = []
>>> b.append(i for i in range(0, 10)) 
>>> b
[<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fda557477d0>]
```

**EDIT**: to address one of the comments.

By the way, every generator object is an iterator and so anywhere where an iterable is expected, a generator expression can be supplied.

Python `list` objects have an `extend` method that accepts one argument, namely, an `iterable`:

> list.extend(iterable)

which "[e]xtend[s] the list by appending all the items from the iterable" (quote from [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)).

Contrast this with

> list.append(x)

which "[a]dd[s] an item to the end of the list" (ibid.).

Your original one-liner code that uses the `append` method can therefore have your desired effect if you were to replace `append` with `extend`.

Of course, you should go with the list comprehension, unless you already have a list with elements and you wish to extend it!

Comment: Added a little more to my answer to address this.

Answer (score 1):

List comprehension :

```py
urls = [item['href'] for item in soup.select('.mydiv a')]
```

Comment: Might want to fix your syntax... you've got an extra `)` there... I'd also suggest the OP uses `soup.select('.mydiv a[href]')` to make sure sure only anchor elements that do actually have an `href` attribute are selected so the `item['href']` won't bork

Comment: Thank you, this worked and what I was looking for. Thank you to @JonClements as well. I've made the edit you suggested